# Django: Any negative effect of assigning value to related object and save

Tags: django

Example:

```
user = instance.user
user.updated_at = now()
user.save()
```

Apart from the "dot optimisation" and "readability", for the sake of curiosity, are there any technical reasons not to do like the following?

```
instance.user.updated_at = now()
instance.user.save()
```

Comment: I have something else to mention, but if you do it using the second approach, your `user` will not get updated! Sounds like django is caching the data for instance's  `user` field?

Comment: @ShangWang the object will be updated on both cases

Comment: @ShangWang I have tested it myself, the second approach does work, but I had an impression it didn't work cause it seemed that the reference is discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is exactly the same. Django will perform the `SELECT` the first time you access the `instance.user` object. This object behaves like any other (it doesn't matter if you use a new reference for it).

If you take into account the moment when the query is performed, you can treat your models pretty much like any python object.